# setting border for table between for loops

Tags: html, css

```
<table class="ordertable">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Item Id</th>
      <th>Item Name</th>
      <th>Unit Price</th>
      <th>Quantity</th>
      <th>Total Price</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>     

  <%
    double total=0.00;
    for(int i=0;i<itemsSize;i++){
      itemColumn=itemsSelected[i].split(";");
      total=total+Double.parseDouble(itemColumn[3]);
      total = Math.round(total * 100);
      total= total/100;                    
  %>

  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td><input class="itemId" id="<%= itemColumn[0] %>" type="text" name="<%= itemColumn[0] %>" value="<%= itemColumn[0] %>"  style="border: 0px solid #000000; text-align: center;" readonly="readonly"/>  </td>
      <td><input id="itemName_<%= itemColumn[0] %>" type="text" name="itemName_<%= itemColumn[0] %>" value="<%= itemColumn[1] %>" style="border: 0px solid #000000; text-align: center;" readonly="readonly"/></td>
      <td><input class="price" id="itemPrice_<%= itemColumn[0] %>" type="text" name="itemPrice_<%= itemColumn[0] %>" value="<%= itemColumn[3] %>" style="border: 0px solid #000000; text-align: center;" readonly="readonly"/></td>
      <td><select class="quantity" id="quantity_<%= itemColumn[0] %>" name="quantity_<%= itemColumn[0] %>" onchange="calculateRowPrice(this.id);">
        <option>1</option>
        <option>2</option>
        <option>3</option>
        <option>4</option>
        <option>5</option>
        </select>
      </td>
      <td><input class="rowTotal" id="total_<%= itemColumn[0] %>" type="text" name="total<%= itemColumn[0] %>" value="<%= itemColumn[3] %>" readonly="readonly" style="border: 0px solid #000000; text-align: center;" readonly="readonly"/></td>
      <br>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  <% }%>
</table>
```

I am trying to set border for table below. I am using for loop to get inputs for my table. But I am getting border only for the header and first row  !You can find below the screenshot if the page. The first row and header alone gets bordered

[image]

Comment: where is your closing braces of for loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are trying to add multiple tbody to the table. Its wrong, it should be multiple rows. Your for loop scope must be inside the tbody. You have to move your for loop inside the tbody, like this:

```
<tbody>

<%
for(loop.....){
%>

<tr>
<td></td>
<td></td>
</tr>

<%}%>

</tbody>
```

Answer (score 0):

Give the table attribute 'border' like

```
<table class="ordertable" border="1">
.....
</table>
```

Comment: I tried it earlier getting same problem. Border is added only for 1st row and header